# popular post weekly and monthly

Tags: loop, query-posts, popular-posts

i want to display popular posts for 1 week ago and 1 month ago.these are codes that i used but these don't work correctly
for 1 week ago

```
<ul>

    <?php
    $week = date('W');
    $year = date('Y');
    query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&cat='.$link1.'&posts_per_page=9&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&year=' . $year . '&weeknum=' . $week);

    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <li>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div style="display:<?php echo $display;?>" class="tooltiptext hidden-xs"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
</li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>

    </ul>
```

for 1 month ago

```
 <ul>

    <?php
    $month = date('m');
    $year = date('Y');
    query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&cat='.$link1.'&posts_per_page=9&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&year=' . $year . '&monthnum=' . $month);

    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

       <li>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div style="display:<?php echo $display;?>" class="tooltiptext hidden-xs"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
</li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>

    </ul>
```

Comment: You don't need to use week and year, this complicates things. Use `1 week ago` or `1 month ago`.

Answer (score 1):

These `$args` is what you need and you may also use that in `query_posts()`;

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => array( 'post' ),
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 9,
        'cat'               => $link1, // try better variable name

        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',          

        'date_query' => array(
        array(
          'after' => '1 months ago',
        ),
        )   
);

$r = null;
$r = new WP_Query($args);
// do something with $r = result
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I provided you some other way than `query_posts()`.
BTW, I like you used `wp_reset_query();` at the end.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have `post_views_count` meta at all? Where you picked this code originally?

Comment: Try to comment `meta_key`, `orderby`, and `order` if you don't have this meta. Also, you may try all categories if you comment `cat`. You have many options for categories, such as `category__in` ... https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query